# Graphing refugee movements using plotly in Python

Tags: python, performance, pandas, data-visualization, geospatial

I've created a simple data visualization in python that shows the movement of refugees around the world. The code works but I feel it is a bit slow. it takes about 10 s (on my hardware at least) to generate the plot.
I'm using a python graphing library called plotly to create the graphics. The user can click an origin country from the dropdown and see the movement of refugees from that country. Due to the way that the graphing library is set up, the dropdown and other interactive objects in the plotly menu are more just meant to restyle certain elements, and in the case of a dropdown menu, no 'value' is returned from the dropdown. What I did to make the dropdown work is I've created a visibility list for every trace in the visualization, perhaps this is part of what is making the code run a bit slow. The other thing that might make the code run slower is I am creating an arrow for each line, but I want the arrow to point correctly relative to the direction of travel so I need to manually calculate the direction of the arrow, which I believe is also making the code run slower.

Some of the steps I've taken to try to speed up my code include concatenating text using join(), using dictionaries for values where possible, and try to minimize the amount of code I use within loops.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

#read in a list of all countries
countries = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jerguy1928/refugee_map/master/rounded_country_centroid_locations.csv')
countries.head()

#this is just me testing things with a slightly different file
# travel_paths = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jerguy1928/refugee_map/master/test_file_3.csv')

#read in a list of refugee movements
travel_paths = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jerguy1928/refugee_map/master/test_file_4.csv')

#sorting the data (my functions require the data to be sorted but my data isn't sorted)
travel_paths.head()
travel_paths.sort_values(["origin","year"],inplace=True)
travel_paths = travel_paths.reset_index(drop=True)

#creating two dictionaries for each countries corresponding latitudes/longitudes
country_lat = dict(zip(countries['country'],countries['lat']))
country_long = dict(zip(countries['country'],countries['long']))

#creates a world map as a backdrop
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations = countries['country_code_3'],
    z = countries['zero'],
    text = countries['country'],
    hoverinfo= 'text',
    marker_line_color='darkgray',
    marker_line_width=0.5,
    showscale= False,

))

# creates the dropdown menu. Each menu entry works by passing a T/F array to the 'visible' property for the map
def dropdown_menu():
    mentioned_countries = []
    menu_data = []
    menu = []
    k = 0
    for j in range(len(travel_paths)):

        ORIGIN = travel_paths['origin'][j]
        desc  = ["Movement of refugees from ",ORIGIN]
        msg = ''.join(desc)
        false_array = list(np.zeros(len(travel_paths),bool))

        if ORIGIN not in mentioned_countries:
            mentioned_countries.append(ORIGIN)
            false_array.insert(j+1,True)
            false_array[0] = True
            menu_data.insert(k,false_array)
            menu.insert(k,dict(args = [{"visible": menu_data[k]},{"title": msg} ], label = ORIGIN, method = "update"))
            k += 1
        else:
            menu_data[k-1].insert(j+1,True)
    #these two lines are used for a 'Show All' paths (all true array)
    true_array = list(np.ones(len(travel_paths),bool))
    menu.insert(0,dict(args = [{"visible": true_array},{"title": "Currently showing all refugees"} ], label = "<i>Show all</i>", method = "update"))
    return menu

#this dictionary descibes the size of each path based on the number of refugees
refugee_lvl = {
    (0,20):0.5,
    (21,50):1,
    (51,100):1.5,
    (101,500):2,
    (501,1000):2.5,
    (1001,10000):3,
    (10001,50000):3.5,
    (50001,100000):4,
    (100001,1000000):4.5,
    (1000001,5000000):5
}

#this dictionary is used for the size of each arrow for each path
marker_lvl = {
    (0,20):3,
    (21,50):3.5,
    (51,100):4,
    (101,500):4.5,
    (501,1000):5,
    (1001,10000):5.5,
    (10001,50000):6,
    (50001,100000):6.5,
    (100001,1000000):7,
    (1000001,5000000):7.5
}
# my code calculates the angle of travel and assigns an appropriate 'arrowhead' (my makeshift draw arrow solution)
angle_calc = {
    (0,22.5):'triangle-up',
    (22.501,67.5):'triangle-ne',
    (67.501,112.5):'triangle-right',
    (112.501,157.5):'triangle-se',
    (157.501,202.5):'triangle-down',
    (202.501,247.5):'triangle-sw',
    (247.501,292.5):'triangle-left',
    (292.501,337.5):'triangle-nw',
    (337.5,360):'triangle-up',
}
#this function returns a value from a dictionary with range values
def get_key(table,num):
    for key in table:
        if key[0] < num < key[1]:
            result = table[key]
            return result
# this function calculates the angle of travel for the travel path
def get_shape(start_lon,start_lat,end_lon,end_lat):
    s2 = (end_lat - start_lat)/(end_lon-start_lon)
    angle = math.atan((900000-s2)/(1+(900000*s2)))
    angle_degrees = math.degrees(angle)
    if start_lat > end_lat:
        angle_degrees +=180
    elif angle_degrees < 0 and start_lat < end_lat:
        angle_degrees += 360
    return get_key(angle_calc,angle_degrees)

#this function draws the traces
def trace_creator():
    #These dictionaries define options for if the refugee movement is internal (IDP) or external (REF)
    IDP = {
        'mode':'markers',
        'size':15,
        'person_type':'IDPs',
        'opacity':1,
        'color':'blue',
        'symbol':'circle-open'
    }
    REF = {
        'mode':'lines+markers',
        'person_type':'Refugees',
        'opacity':[0,1],
        'color':'green',
    }
    #loop through all travel paths
    for i in range(len(travel_paths)):
        ORIGIN = travel_paths['origin'][i]
        DESTINATION = travel_paths['destination'][i]
        YEAR = travel_paths['year'][i]
        REFUGEES = travel_paths['refugees'][i]
        ORIGIN_LAT = country_lat.get(ORIGIN)
        ORIGIN_LON = country_long.get(ORIGIN)
        DEST_LAT = country_lat.get(DESTINATION)
        DEST_LON = country_long.get(DESTINATION)
        lat_list = [ORIGIN_LAT]
        lon_list = [ORIGIN_LON]

        #If internal movement
        if ORIGIN == DESTINATION:
            mode_val = IDP.get('mode')
            size_val = IDP.get('size')
            person_type = IDP.get('person_type')
            marker_opacity = IDP.get('opacity')
            marker_color = IDP.get('color')
            marker_symbol = IDP.get('symbol')
        #if external movement
        else:
            lat_list.append(DEST_LAT)
            lon_list.append(DEST_LON)
            mode_val = REF.get('mode')
            size_val = get_key(marker_lvl,REFUGEES)
            person_type = REF.get('person_type')
            marker_opacity = REF.get('opacity')
            marker_color = REF.get('color')
            marker_symbol = get_shape(ORIGIN_LON,ORIGIN_LAT,DEST_LON,DEST_LAT)
        text_list = [ORIGIN,' → ', DESTINATION, "<br>", person_type, ": ", format(REFUGEES,',d')]    
        s = ''
        # passing the values from above to the add_trace method
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scattergeo(
                    lat = lat_list,
                    lon = lon_list,
                    mode = mode_val,
                    marker= dict(
                        size = size_val,
                        symbol = marker_symbol,
                        color = marker_color,
                        opacity = marker_opacity
                        ),
                    line = dict(width = get_key(refugee_lvl,REFUGEES),color = 'red'),
                    showlegend= True,
                    legendgroup= str(YEAR),
                    name = str(YEAR),
                    text= s.join(text_list),
                    hoverinfo= 'text'
                    )),
trace_creator()
#adding titles/dropdown menu
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        go.layout.Updatemenu(
            buttons = dropdown_menu(),
            direction="down",
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.37,
            xanchor="left",
            y= 1.08,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
    ],
    title_text = 'Movement of UNHCR Refugees (Choose origin country from the list)',
    geo = go.layout.Geo(
        projection_type = 'mercator',
        showland = True,
        showcountries= True,
        landcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)',
        countrycolor = 'rgb(204, 204, 204)',  
    ),    
)
#draw the figures
fig.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code to see which parts take a longer time? It's entirely possible it is slow because you're downloading data from the web

Answer (score 2):

> The other thing that might make the code run slower is I am creating an arrow for each line, but I want the arrow to point correctly relative to the direction of travel so I need to manually calculate the direction of the arrow, which I believe is also making the code run slower.

That would be it.  `trace_creator()` alone takes 10s on my machine, which is basically all of the runtime for me.

Half of it is `go.Scattergeo` calls, the other `fig.add_trace`.

Unfortunately I don't know the library, but, I imagine there most be some construction where you're only adding a single `Scattergeo` with all of those paths included.  If not, then, perhaps they can be grouped and so the number of them could be reduced from the ~1k of them?

---

How did I find out?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python) for how to time a block of code.  I inserted some `timeit` timers and just narrowed it down.

The other options is, as was already said, to use [a profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script).